# bash: How to place variable into specific string

Tags: bash, replace

I have the following command in a bash script:

```
$prefixBioAwk -c fastx '{ if(length($seq) > 600) { print ">"$name; print $seq }}' my.fasta > short.fasta
```

Now I want to make the number `600` flexible by inserting the var `$myVar` (which contains an iteger) there.

How do I do it?

Comment: If `$prefixBioAwk` is anything like Awk, `awk -v variable="$value" 'length($seq) > variable { print ">" $name; print $seq }' my.fasta`

Comment: Seems to be this one: https://github.com/lh3/bioawk

Comment: exactly, sorry, forgot to mention bioawk

Comment: hmmm... `-v' seems to have another function in bioawk. is there another way?

Comment: Looking at the github page, it seems `-v` serves same purpose as in `awk`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is posted as a bash question, I'm answering with a bash response rather than something bioawk specific:

`myVar=600 prefixBioAwk -c fastx '{ if(length($seq) > '$myVar') { print ">"$name; print $seq }}' my.fasta > short.fasta`

The key is to get out of the single quotes so that the shell can interpret the variable and substitute its value.

Comment: ups, surprisingly easy. I have to have a look at the logics of bash replacement, quotes, etc. Many thanks